# Run time error 3061 Too few parameters expected 4

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Customer set [FirstName] = " & Me.FirstName & _
                                    " ,[LastName] = " & Me.LastName & _
                                    " ,[PhoneNumber] = '" & Me.PhoneNumber & _
                                    "' ,[Address] = '" & Me.Address & _
                                    "' ,[City] = " & Me.City & _
                                    " ,[State] = " & Me.State & _
                                    " ,[ZipCode] = " & Me.ZipCode & " WHERE ([E-mail] = '" & Me.email & "')"
```

what is wrong with this update query. Please help.

Comment: From the looks of the error, the table you are trying to update does not contain those column names (or at least 4 of them). Post the info for your table for additional assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Once again, consider SQL parameterization, an industry best practice when working with SQL, which *is* supported in MS Access using `PARAMETERS` clause and [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx). You avoid messy concatenation, quote enclosures (which you are missing quite a bit for your text fields), and possibly SQL injection as such fields are open to users.

**SQL** *(save as a stored Access query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [FirstNameParam] Text(255), [LastNameParam] Text(255),
           [PhoneNumberParam] Text(255), [AddressParam] Text(255),
           [CityParam] Text(255), [StateParam] Text(255),
           [ZipCodeParam] Text(255), [EmailParam] Text(255);
UPDATE Customer 
   SET [FirstName] = [FirstNameParam],
       [LastName] = [LastNameParam],
       [PhoneNumber] = [PhoneNumberParam],
       [Address] = [AddressParam],
       [City] = [CityParam],
       [State] = [StateParam],
       [ZipCode] = [ZipCodeParam]
WHERE ([E-mail] = [EmailParam]);
```

**VBA**

```vb
Dim qdef As QueryDef

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedParameterQuery")

' BIND VALUES TO PARAMETER PLACEHOLDERS
qdef![FirstNameParam] = Me.FirstName
qdef![LastNameParam] = Me.LastName
qdef![PhoneNumberParam] = Me.PhoneNumber
qdef![AddressParam] = Me.Address
qdef![CityParam] = Me.City
qdef![StateParam] = Me.State
qdef![ZipCodeParam] = Me.ZipCode
qdef![EmailParam] = Me.Email

' EXECUTE ACTION QUERY
qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```

Comment: Did you accidentally leave "Param" off the name of LastNameParam when calling it in your UPDATE sql/Set command?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess from looking at your SQL and the error - I suspect your 4 field names with two words should likely have spaces between the two words: `[FirstName]` becomes `[First Name]`, `[Last Name]` becomes `[Last Name]` and so on

So SQL string should actually be

```
"UPDATE Customer set [First Name] = " & Me.FirstName & _
                                        " ,[Last Name] = " & Me.LastName & _
                                        " ,[Phone Number] = '" & Me.PhoneNumber & _
                                        "' ,[Address] = '" & Me.Address & _
                                        "' ,[City] = " & Me.City & _
                                        " ,[State] = " & Me.State & _
                                        " ,[Zip Code] = " & Me.ZipCode & " WHERE ([E-mail] = '" & Me.email & "')"
```

As @Jiggles32 says - the only way to know for sure is to show us your field names from the Customer table